# Event Listener do not work properly, works on chrome and do not work on firefox

Tags: javascript, html

i have a Event Listener on my code, but that only works on Web google chrome, this event listener don't work on firefox or google chrome on android.

So, this event listener only recognizes when the user types an integer, this works fine on web google chrome, but on other browsers do not work.

On web firefox, does not recognize any letter, even integers. On google chrome Android let type everything.

```js
document.getElementById("minutes").addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode < 48 || evt.keyCode > 57)
    evt.preventDefault();

}, false);
```

Comment: is `#minutes` input?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: try the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `keydown` or `keyup`, this should work. Also you can try to use `keyup` with `ìnput`, like `.addEventListener("input keyup", function(evt){}`

Comment: @JoséMiranda please don't forget to check as answer and upvote, you are welcome!

Comment: Please do not beg/ask for up votes and acceptance, it you put up good answers you will get those.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss i'm ask only when author solved a problem. but thanks